# problems with bootstrap navbar dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have copied  from bootstrap default navbar, and this dropdown is not working, I have all js and css files included in code:

```
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">username <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></a></li>
                  </ul>
```

and this are bootstrap js included in end of body:

```
<script src="{% static 'js\bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js\bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

and the css :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css\bootstrap.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css\bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css\bootstrap-theme.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css\bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' bootstrap.js:143

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' bootstrap.min.js:6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to include the jquery.min.js file in the body section of your html file.
Include the below statement in your code,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can find more about navbar dropdowns at this page,

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code before closing `</body>` tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** you need to include the files in the same order as i mentioned.please let me now if that work :)